# Package.Appxmanifest - Any way to get to portion of this in code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, appxmanifest

I know you can get to `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current` and use Id.Name to get the name, but this seems to be the Package Name in my manifest.  A rather long string of numbers and letters.

How can I get to the Package Display Name, Publisher Display Name that are in the manifest from inside the code.  I would rather make this dynamic.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The manifest is an xml file so you can query it with Linq to XML:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Storage;

private async void GetInfo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("AppxManifest.xml");
    string manifestXml = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(manifestXml);
    XNamespace packageNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest";
    var displayName = (from name in doc.Descendants(packageNamespace + "DisplayName")
                       select name.Value).First();
    var publisherDsplName = (from publisher in doc.Descendants(packageNamespace + "PublisherDisplayName")
                             select publisher.Value).First();
    string output = "DisplayName: " + displayName + ", PublisherDisplayName: " + publisherDsplName;
    txtBlock.Text = output;
}
```

Comment: I don't particularly like that way.  I'll just throw something in the resource files to cover these things and call it a day.